# deserialize inherited object

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have `MongoCollection<myObject>`.

Some of the "myObject" in the collection contains another object (lets say "myObject2") and some of them contains an object that inherited from "myObject2" ("myInheritedObjet")

Now I want to deserialize the Items from the collection, but I'm getting an error because "myObject2" don't have some of the attributes of "myInheritedObjet".

> An error occurred while deserializing the "myobject" property: Element
>   'Name' does not match any field or property of class "myobject"

For example:

`MongoCollection<Person>`

```
Person
    string name;
    Animal[] pets;

Animal
    string AType;

Dog : Animal
    string Name;
```

If Person have a Dog, this person can't deserialize because the Animal Type dosn't have "Name".

How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found this: [deserializing polymorphic classes](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#specifying-known-types)

All I needed to do is mapping the base class to the subclass with:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(subclass)]
class BaseClass {...}
```